# Excel: Merge duplicate values in output 2D array from FILTER() function

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, duplicates

I have a 2D array that is the result of a FILTER() function, similar to:

```c-like
=FILTER(
    INDEX(dataTable, SEQUENCE(ROWS(dataTable)), {5, 12, 2, 8}),
    dataTable[Status]=A1
)
```

The source data is a table of orders in an external spreadsheet, and the above provides a summary of orders with a given status.

This works fine, but in the source data there may be duplicate line-items for a single order. For example:

| Order No. | Items | Ordered | Delivered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 123 | Apples | 1 Jan | 2 Jan |
| 123 | Oranges | 1 Jan | 5 Jan |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**What I am looking for** is a way of condensing the results so that:

- Where there are duplicate values in one specific column, only the details for the first row are shown
- All of the duplicate values for one column are shown/concatenated

So the resulting table would look something like:

| Order No. | Items | Ordered | Delivered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 123 | Apples, Orange | 1 Jan | 2 Jan |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

For the sake of relating the code example above with this example, assume that in the source data:

- Column 5 is "Order No." (the column we are filtering for duplicates of).
- Column 12 is "Items" (the column we are looking to list all values of for that Orer No. if there is a duplicate)
- Other columns in the output table may pull results from columns out of order, e.g. Column 1 or Column 50.

It is also a requirement that the source data cannot be altered, and that this is done with formulae, (not using macros, 3rd party plugins, etc.)

Is this possible?

Comment: Your current formula is indexing three columns - {3,5,12} - from the source table, though your example tables include four. Perhaps make consistent and also clarify which index refers to which field.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=REDUCE(A1:D1,UNIQUE(A2:A5),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,HSTACK(y,TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(B2:B5,A2:A5=y)),XLOOKUP(y,A2:A5,C2:D5)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula

```
=LET(x,A2:A5,y,UNIQUE(x),a,MAP(y,LAMBDA(z,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(B:B,A:A=z)))),HSTACK(y,a))
```

[image]

If you want to add other columns then try-

```
=LET(x,A2:INDEX(A2:A50000,COUNTA(A2:A50000)),y,UNIQUE(x),
itms,BYROW(y,LAMBDA(items,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=items))))),
odt,BYROW(y,LAMBDA(ordt,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,TEXT(UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,A:A=ordt)),"d/m/e")))),
ddt,BYROW(y,LAMBDA(drdt,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,TEXT(UNIQUE(FILTER(D:D,A:A=drdt)),"d/m/e")))),
HSTACK(y,itms,odt,ddt))
```

[image]

Comment: Remember that `FILTER` does **not** explicitly detect the last-used cell within the range(s) passed, and so the condition you are passing to that function (`A:A=z`) will be forced to calculate over all 1,048,576 cells.

Comment: @JosWoolley Yes, Then we can narrow passing input parameter by using some other formula.